# Update Contact number as STARRED in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to mark specific contact number as favorite(Starred). For that I am using following query:

```
    String selectPhone = Phone._ID + "=?";
    String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{ NUMBER_ID }; 
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Phone.STARRED, 0);

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
            .withValue(Phone.STARRED, 1)
            .build()); 
    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Above code is not throwing any exception but not updating database as well. If you have solution please let me know. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

Do this to Mark particular contact as STARRED.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String[] fv = new String[] { "Juned" };
        values.put(Contacts.STARRED, 1);
        getContentResolver().update(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, values,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "= ?", fv);
```

Just change the second parameter 1 to 0 in this line `values.put(Contacts.STARRED, 1);` to unfavorite the starred contact.

Comment: let me know if is there any problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I actually wanted to mark specific number as a STARRED. I am already marking Contact as a STARRED.

Comment: ohh i see,can you try to pass number instead of name mark particular number as STARRED ?

Comment: For every number we have specific _ID. I tried using it and it is updating number field. But it is not updating STARRED field. That is the problem..

Comment: @juned : is there any possibility to check if particular number is starred or not ?

Comment: @Vaishali since a long I haven't work on this, but I think there is a way to find out starred contacts. When I get time I will check regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The "Starred" property belongs to the Contact entity. At least, this is what i get from the ContactsContract.class definitions.
I use code like:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{contactRawId})
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED, isFavorite ? 1 : 0)
                    .build());
```

Where the parameters are (int)contactRawId, (boolean)isFavorite